# Connect to particular wireless hotspot in distributed network?

Tags: wireless-networking, nas, hotspot

I have a wireless network in my flat which is provided by two Wi-Fi routers. 
Router 1: D-Link wireless router connected directly to Internet.
Router 2: Synology NAS with built in WiFi router connected to Router 1 via LAN cable.

Exactly the same network is setup on both routers, with the same SSID, password, etc.

So in fact I have 2 access points to my network which differ by the router MAC address, and channel. As far as I understand, the device (laptop, smartphone) is automatically finding the access point with better signal and connects to it. But I would like to manually select the access point which I want to connect to.

The reason for this is that I'd like to connect directly to my NAS (Router 2) over its WiFi, instead of transferring data over WiFi to Router 1, and then via LAN to Router 2.

So is this possible at all? And if yes, then what are the tools for that. I'm using Mac Book Pro, with Mac OS X 10.8 installed.

Comment: Given the wifi bottleneck in both scenarios, going direct the NAS won't be any quicker, if that is the intention.  How about using different SSIDs for the two APs?

Comment: I'm not sure if that will really make any difference, but if, for example, I will be downloading some large files from NAS with one device, and at the same time downloading something large from internet with the other device, both downloads will go through the same WiFi router. Consequently my internal traffic will affect the overall speed of Internet access. Having different SSID for network from NAS router of course can do the work but I just don't like the idea of having 2 different networks at home.

Comment: Using a different SSID doesn't imply two different networks, they would both be on the same network.  It just means that you can decide which AP you want to connect to by choosing the appropriate SSID for the AP you want.

Comment: Yes, really, that works as a single network, so that can be a solution for me, but still I'm curious if is it possible to connect manually to a certain access point having the same SSID.

Comment: Yep.  I am not sure about OSX, but if using wpa_supplicant (as in linux), you can specify the MAC (bssid) of the AP you want to connect to.

Comment: Doesn't seem like you can: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6958/can-i-connect-to-a-specific-access-point-by-bssid

Comment: Yes, seems like that. It's a pity that this feature has been blocked in last version of Mac OS.